# WPF Xaml Binding class instance using INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: wpf

I have a problem working with databinding in XAML.The problem is the following, I want update a label from an istance of my ExampleClass.
I see two method but one of this not work.
The first is (in example code label1): in your xaml.cs define a property that is your reference to an instance of ExampleClass and in your xaml simply write YourPropertyReferenceToExampleClass.PropertyName but it not work
The second is simple (in example code label2), set dataContext for your label to an istance of ExampleClass and in your xaml simply write PropertyName.

Below the code (Xaml):

```
<Window x:Class="SimpleBinding.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SimpleBinding"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="137.03" Width="255.263">
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="45,76,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <Label x:Name="label" Content="{Binding One}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,14,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label x:Name="label1" Content="{Binding T.Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label x:Name="label2" Content="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

</Grid>
```

Below the code (Xaml.cs):

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace SimpleBinding
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private string _one;
        public string One
        {
            get => _one; set
            {
                _one = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("One");
            }
        }

        public ExampleClass T { get; private set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            One = "ciao";
            T = new ExampleClass();
            label2.DataContext = T;
            T.Name = "foo";
        }
    }
}
```

Below the code (ExampleClass.cs):

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace SimpleBinding
{
    public class ExampleClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _name;

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _name;
            }

            set
            {
                if (_name == value) return;

                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

How the first method should work?

Comment: It is more consistent and easier to implement this property as a dependency property instead of a property.

Comment: The wpf equivalent to winforms label is textblock. A label is a content control which will by default generate a textblock as content. The fact you have this sort of "hidden" textblock can then lead to surprises later on. Also. You should use a separate class ( a viewmodel ) rather than window code behind. Otherwise you lose a lot of the benefits of binding. EG you need to instantiate the whole window for any automated tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fire the PropertyChanged event for the `T` property:

```
private ExampleClass t;
public ExampleClass T
{
    get { return t; }
    private set
    {
        if (t != value)
        {
            t = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(T));
        }
    }
}
```

The change notification is required when you assign a new value to the `T` property and want a `{Binding T.Name}` to update its target:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    T = new ExampleClass(); // requires change notification
    label2.DataContext = T; // avoid this
    T.Name = "foo";
}
```

You should prefer using `{Binding T.Name}` over `{Binding Name}` to avoid the need to set any other DataContext than that of the MainWindow.